# SSRS Report Subscription and Time Sensitive Query Based Default Value

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am creating a subscription for a report and want to use the default value for a query based parameter that is time sensitive. My question is, when is the default value set for the parameter? At the moment the subscription is created or executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query based default value is calculated at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

How the default value for parameter is get calculated at execution time? Are you using the cascading parameter?

When you check the subscription setting page, the default value for parameter is the same as the default you set for that parameter in SSDT, and the cascading parameter value will be changed corresponding to the first default parameter value.

Comment: The report manager will choose the default value as you set automatically for you

Comment: Yes it's a cascading parameter and the default is query based. The query for the default value is time sensitive so it may change from the time the subscription was created to when it is actually executed.

Comment: it did not give you the default value back when the `use default` is checked?

Comment: When you are in the `new subscription` page for report parameter and delivery settings, at this time the report manager has already pick the default value for you.